# What Data Service to use + simple Example (WPF C# SQL)

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, dataservice

We have WPF Applications and we want to develop some Xamarin Apps too. What we need is a Data Service that's not WCF (because it doesn't work with Xamarin). I am clueless since I have never worked with a Data Service.

What can I use that works with both WPF and Xamarin Applications?

Where can it run?

Are there any simple examples?

Comment: What do you mean "Data Service" and why would you need one instead of a service that actually implements a business scenario like `get active orders for this user`? Data services are generally a smel that suggests you are trying to use a service as if it were a local database. WCF implements SOAP services. The *client* typically doesn't care how a SOAP service is implemented server-side. It's far more common to use REST-style services through eg ASP.NET Web API these days.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is working in xamarin =>
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/data-cloud/web-services/walkthrough-working-with-wcf
But if you want to use something else that have a look on asp.net web api for a rest => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/consuming/rest

Answer (score 0):

any restful service including WCF and web api or even java etc will work with any xamarin client